# Create Ransack object without querying DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I'd like to be able to create a Ransack::Search object to be passed into a search_form_for, but the initial creation of the search object queries the database, wich I don't want.

I want to show an initial blank form with Ransack::Search options to search, without calling the database.

How can I do that ?

thanks,

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arel relations (ie. queries) are lazily-executed on first reference to the results, so you should find that you can create a search object and pass it to the form, without it calling the db, so long as you don't reference the .result method anywhere.

e.g.

```
// in your controller
my_query = MyModelClass.where{ id.gt(0) }
@q = my_query.search( params[:q] )

// in your view
search_form_for( @q, (...other options...) )
```

Any of these will trigger the db query to be actually performed:

```
- @q.results.each do |result| 
- for result in @q.results
- @q.results.count
- @q.results.to_a
- @q.results.size
// ....etc
```

But so long as you only use the search object for your form, it should not get executed.

*Of course, if you're testing this from the console, make sure that you put `;nil` at the end of the line, otherwise the console will print the last thing evaluated, which will cause the query to be run!*

Comment: yes, I solved my problem from the github repository, but forgot to add the answer here, thanks! :-)